# First address of struct

Tags: c, memory, struct

Hello I am working on a `struct` based project. I have a problem with saving my first address of my struct. Problem is not with my N function it works fine. My problem is that in my V function it printfs only my last structure list. I want it to printf all of my information from my struct not only the last one. I hope I made myself understandable

**CODE:**

```
typedef struct stuff {
    char signatura[12];
    char isbn[15];
    char kniha[100];
    char autori[100];
    int datum;
    int preukaz;
    struct stuff *p_dalsi;

} STUFF;

STUFF *alokuj(void){
    STUFF *p_pom;
    p_pom=(STUFF *) malloc (sizeof(STUFF));
    return p_pom;
}

void nacitaj(STUFF *p_akt){
    FILE *fr;
    int pocet_zaznam=0, pocet_enter=0, i;
    char c, s[100];

    if ((fr = fopen("KNIZNICA.TXT","r")) == NULL){
        printf("Zaznamy neboli nacitane\n");
    }
    while((c=getc(fr))!= EOF) { 
        if(c=='\n') pocet_enter++;
    }
    pocet_zaznam=(pocet_enter+1)/7;jeden zaznam ma 7 casti
    rewind(fr);i


    for (i=1;i<=pocet_zaznam;i++){

        fgets(s,100,fr);    //vynechanie prveho riadku v subore
        fgets(p_akt->signatura,12,fr);
        fgets(p_akt->isbn,15,fr);
        fgets(p_akt->kniha,100,fr);
        fgets(p_akt->autori,100,fr);
        fscanf(fr,"%d\n",&p_akt->datum);
        fscanf(fr,"%d\n",&p_akt->preukaz);

        p_akt->p_dalsi=NULL;
    }


    printf("Nacitalo sa %d zaznamov\n",pocet_zaznam);
    fclose(fr);

}

void vypis(STUFF *p_akt) {
    int zaznam_poradie=1;

    while(p_akt!=NULL) {
        printf("%d.\n",zaznam_poradie);
        printf("signatura: %s",p_akt->signatura);
        printf("isbn: %s",p_akt->isbn);
        printf("kniha: %s",p_akt->kniha);
        printf("autori: %s",p_akt->autori);
        printf("datum: %d\n",p_akt->datum);
        printf("datum: %d\n",p_akt->preukaz);
        zaznam_poradie++;

    p_akt=p_akt->p_dalsi;
    }

}

int main() {
    char c;
    STUFF *p_prv = NULL;
    STUFF *p_akt = NULL;


    p_akt = p_prv;
    p_prv = (STUFF *)malloc(sizeof(STUFF));

    while(c!='K') {
        c = getchar();
        if(c=='N') {
            p_akt = p_prv;
            nacitaj(p_akt);
        }
        if(c=='V') {
            p_akt = p_prv;
            vypis(p_akt);
        }

        if(c=='P');
        if(c=='Z');
        if(c=='H');
        if(c=='A');
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.  2. Indentation and formatting are important.

Comment: "My problem is that in my V function it printfs only my last structure list." That means you pass it the pointer to the last element in the list. Without seeing more of the code, more I cannot say.

Comment: Is this Czech? Or Slovakian?

Comment: I completed the code above. I just dont understand why my V function printfs only 1 (last) element of my struct. Any ideas ? And its Slovakian :)

Comment: Note that `getchar` returns `int` and thus `c` must be declared as an `int`.

Comment: You don't even initialize `c` before `while (c!='K')`. Get back to square one in writing this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your 'N-function'; it does not create a list, and neither does the code calling it.

The code supplied won't compile:

```
pocet_zaznam=(pocet_enter+1)/7;jeden zaznam ma 7 casti
rewind(fr);i
```

The `jeden ... casti` part is presumably a comment without its comment marker.  The `i` seems to be simply extraneous.  These issues can be ignored for analyis.

However, it appears that the function reads the file, counting the number of newlines in it, and then rereads the file to load the data.  It keeps on writing over the same single structure, though, and makes no attempt to allocate new ones or link the current one with the previous ones.  Note that your allocation function, `alokuj()`, is not called in the code you show.

When the 'V-function' is finally called, the only data it has to work with is the last entry that was read, because the information for the previous ones has been overwritten.

You need to rework the code to allocate a new structure for each item to be read, to collect them all into a list, and (probably) to return the head of the list to the calling code.

You should also be error checking functions that can fail.  You do check `fopen()`, but you then continue using the return value even if it is NULL — you shouldn't, and you should report the error to standard error, not standard output.  You should check memory allocation; you should check `fgets()`.  Granted, when the file was opened, it contained a certain number of lines; it may be truncated by the time you get to reread the file, though, so you still need to check.  You might need to remove the newlines from the strings, too (`fgets()` includes the newline in the string).

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct stuff
{
    char signatura[12];
    char isbn[15];
    char kniha[100];
    char autori[100];
    int datum;
    int preukaz;
    struct stuff *p_dalsi;
} STUFF;

static STUFF *alokuj(void)
{
    STUFF *p_pom = (STUFF *) malloc (sizeof(STUFF));
    if (p_pom == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p_pom;
}

static void vypis(STUFF *p_akt)
{
    int zaznam_poradie=1;

    while (p_akt != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d.\n", zaznam_poradie);
        printf("signatura: %s", p_akt->signatura);
        printf("isbn: %s", p_akt->isbn);
        printf("kniha: %s", p_akt->kniha);
        printf("autori: %s", p_akt->autori);
        printf("datum: %d\n", p_akt->datum);
        printf("datum: %d\n", p_akt->preukaz);
        p_akt=p_akt->p_dalsi;
        zaznam_poradie++;
    }
}

static STUFF *nacitaj(void)
{
    FILE *fr;
    int   pocet_zaznam = 0;
    int   pocet_enter = 0;
    int   i;
    char  s[100];
    int   c;

    if ((fr = fopen("KNIZNICA.TXT", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Zaznamy neboli nacitane\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((c = getc(fr)) != EOF)
    { 
        if (c == '\n')
            pocet_enter++;
    }

    pocet_zaznam = (pocet_enter+1)/7;
    rewind(fr);
    STUFF *p_head = 0;
    STUFF *p_last = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= pocet_zaznam; i++)
    {
        STUFF *p_akt = alokuj();
        if (fgets(s, 100, fr)                   == 0 || // 100 should be sizeof(s) ... etc
            fgets(p_akt->signatura, 12, fr)     == 0 ||
            fgets(p_akt->isbn, 15, fr)          == 0 ||
            fgets(p_akt->kniha, 100, fr)        == 0 ||
            fgets(p_akt->autori, 100, fr)       == 0 ||
            fscanf(fr, "%d\n", &p_akt->datum)   != 1 ||
            fscanf(fr, "%d\n", &p_akt->preukaz) != 1)
        // "%d\n" would be bad for interactive I/O; OK for file I/O
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Data format error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        p_akt->p_dalsi = NULL;

        //printf("Read entry %d:\n", i);
        //vypis(p_akt);

        if (p_head == 0)
            p_head = p_akt;
        else
            p_last->p_dalsi = p_akt;
        p_last = p_akt;
    }

    printf("Nacitalo sa %d zaznamov\n", pocet_zaznam);
    fclose(fr);
    return p_head;
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    STUFF *p_akt = NULL;

    while (c!='K')
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        else if (c == 'N')
            p_akt = nacitaj();
        else if (c == 'V')
            vypis(p_akt);
        else if (c != '\n')
            fprintf(stderr, "Unrecognized commmand: %c\n", c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Data file KNIZNICA.TXT

```
Rubbish1
signature1
0123456789212
Writing C Programs on Stack Overflow
Jonathan Leffler
20120505
1234
Rubbish2
signature2
9876543210212
Rewriting C Programs on Stack Overflow
Leffler, Jonathan
20130505
2234
```

Example run (program name `ak`):

```
$ ./ak
N
Nacitalo sa 2 zaznamov
V
1.
signatura: signature1
isbn: 0123456789212
kniha: Writing C Programs on Stack Overflow
autori: Jonathan Leffler
datum: 20120505
datum: 1234
2.
signatura: signature2
isbn: 9876543210212
kniha: Rewriting C Programs on Stack Overflow
autori: Leffler, Jonathan
datum: 20130505
datum: 2234
$
```

I'd normally use `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)` in the `for` loop — it is more idiomatic C than `for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)`.  The functions are made static because I use compilation flags that insist on functions being declared before being defined or used:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition ak.c -o ak
```

Because I compile like that, I don't think the cast on `malloc()` is an issue.  Those who complain about the cast on `malloc()` are primarily concerned about 'what happens if `malloc()` is not declared', but that's already a warning when I'm compiling (which I effectively treat as an error; I'd add `-Werror` to ensure it was formally an error), so it is a non-issue to me.  (The code shown can also be compiled as a valid C++ program because the cast is present; if the cast was missing, it would not be a valid C++ program.  It is not a good C++ program; it is a C program.)  Since I used the V-function to debug the N-function, I moved the V-function above the N-function.

Comment: You SIR, you deserve a medal for this post. I am a kind of person who really wants to learn something and the best way is to learn on my own mistakes. You showed couple of them and remade the code and now it works. Last 30 minutes i was analysing what you have told me here and now all makes perfect sense!! i am glad that there are always people like you who can not only help but also explain!! THANK YOU SIR!

Comment: Given that there is a linked list, you really don't need to reread the file; you could read entries until you come across an error or EOF.  I've not fixed that.  If you do fix that, then it would be possible to read from the keyboard rather than a fixed file.  There are a lot of changes that I'd make, still, but this seemed to be an appropriate balance between what was necessary to make the code reasonably reliable and what could be done.  Never be satisfied with your code as 'perfect'.  However, there is usually a point where it reaches 'good enough', and that's the time to stop tinkering.