# c program not outputting as expected

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory, stdin

So I have this program that I put together from head first c. It is from Chapter 6 - the data structures chapter... My problem is that the output displays all previous listed entries as well as the last entered name to the standard input. So instead showing everything printed once the program prints everything almost twice. It is hard for me to describe. If you just copy and paste it into a text-editor on your machine and run the code you will see what I mean.

The book shows the program taking a file of island names using the < redirection tool. When I try this it prints the first name the second name and the first name. Then the next name and the second and first name...Then the next name and the third, second, and first name...etc depending how many names there are. This behavior also occurs when entering text in the terminal in standard input.

*IF I change the code to say display(next) it works closer to what I would expect but it still prints out an extra blank line and there are probably memory leaks*

This code is pretty much over my head can someone figure out why it is printing like this?

I would ask at the head first c discussion board but I wanted to ask stackoverflow first and get an immediate answer.

My code is below. If you copy and paste it into a text editor it should not look like a wall of text.

Happy coding.

```
#include <stdio.h> // basic input output
#include <stdlib.h>  // for obtaining and releasing heap memory malloc and free...
#include <string.h>  // for the stringdup method

typedef struct island {
    char *name;
    char *opens;
    char *closes;
    struct island *next;
} island;

void display(island *madonna);

island* create(char *name);

void release(island *start);

int main()
{
    /* create islands */
    island *start = NULL;
    island *i = NULL;
    island *next = NULL;
    char name[80];
    puts("enter island name...");
    for(; fgets(name, 80, stdin) != NULL; i = next) {
        next = create(name);
        if(start == NULL)
            start = next;
        if (i != NULL)
            i -> next = next;

        display(start);

    }
    release(start);

}

// display method
void display(island *start)
{
    island *i = start;

    if (i == NULL)
        puts("i equals NULL ");

    for(;i != NULL; i = i ->next) {
        printf("Name: %s open: %s-%s\n", i->name, i->opens, i->closes);
    }
}

// create method
island* create(char *name)
{
    island *i = malloc(sizeof(island));
    i->name = strdup(name);
    i->opens = "09:00";
    i->closes = "17:00";
    i->next = NULL;
    return i;
}

// release method
void release(island *start)
{
    island *i = start;
    island *next = NULL;
    for(; i != NULL; i = next) {
        next = i-> next;
        free(i->name); // must free this first because of strdup uses heap memory
        free(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do `display(i);` instead of `display(start);`

Comment: ...or move the `display()` outside of the loop.

Comment: i can't believe someone marked down this question. Anyways thanks for the help so far. @WhozCraig if I move display() out of the loop the program just sits there taking input but not actually displaying anything...

Comment: @user2085446, the downvote could be for any of the following: 1) What is the expected input, expected output and actual output? 2) Title somewhat undescriptive 3) Not explaining what the code is meant to do/anything you've tried

Comment: @MrLister thank-you for the help. i tried this but it still does not work as expected. the first time through i is NULL prints then the subsequent times it prints the last two entries along with the latest entry as one and the previous name as the other thing printed

Comment: @Patashu thanks for explaining. This post rocks compared to a lot of other posts. I was confused.

Comment: Do ***not*** use _any_ spaces on either side of either the `.` operator or the `->` operator.  They bind incredibly tightly; they should be written to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working-as-designed (WAD).  It is designed to print the complete list after each entry is read — that's what the `display(start)` does in the loop.  You could help yourself by either echoing the input (`printf("Read: %s", name);` where there's no newline in the format because the name still includes the newline) or by tagging the display with `printf("Printing list:\n");` before the call to `display()` (or both).  If you get rid of the newline from the name, you'll need to adjust the 'echo' operation.

Learning how to create helpful diagnostic messages is a valuable technique; one of the key points is to ensure that the output lines end with a newline so there's a decent chance you'll see the printing as it occurs, rather than some indeterminate time later.  Another key point is printing inputs so that you know what the code is working on rather than thinking you know what the code is working on.  Printing the complete list on each iteration also helps ensure that the list is being constructed correctly.  You can find examples on SO where the list was not constructed correctly (e.g. [First address of struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385697/first-address-of-struct)).  Had the complete list been printed on each iteration, the problem would have been more obvious.

The trouble, therefore, seems to be that your expectations do not match what the code is designed to do.

Comment: If I change the code to display(next) in the for loop in main() it prints only what was last entered or the entire contents of a file of names with < redirection. the file of names for me is a name then a return then another island name, etc. if I move display(next) and release(start) into the for loop of main() i get an endless loop with the second island name printing to infinity..

Comment: i dont think this answers anything really but i was frustrated and i appreciated the help @Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

> "My problem is that the output displays all previous listed entries as
>   well as the last entered name to the standard input."

```
 for(;i != NULL; i = i ->next) {
        printf("Name: %s open: %s-%s\n", i->name, i->opens, i->closes);
```

by the way you told us your problem but you did not tell us what your program should do

Comment: already have this code in the display method... did anyone try copy and pasting then running the code on their machine?

Comment: there is the problem. I do not need to copy paste your code. Just read it, take a paper or whatever and think about what you wrote. there are 2 loop in your program

Comment: @user2085446 While it may be a very low-quality post, please consider sharing your opinion in a more constructive manner in the future. Thanks!